# Is it possible to target ef and ef core based on target framework in multi target framework class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to build a c# class library that can be used in our new .NET6 services and also in our older clients/services that target .NET 461 or .net standard.

So I'm building a class library where I target multiple target frameworks:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;net461;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I need to access our database for some crud functions and I want to use Entity framework (Core) to do this. Because of the multi target frameworks, I cant't just install one version of ef (some need ef and some need ef core).

Is it possible to include ef for a target framework and ef core for an other target framework? How can I do this?

Comment: No, it isn't possible to multi-target EF6 and EF Core. They're completely incompatible with each other with many breaking API changes (e.g. all the types are in different namespaces).

Comment: Check how it is done with [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) - `LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`